# How do I serve a global AnalyzerConfig file from a NuGet package?

Tags: .net, msbuild

We have about 35 different .NET 6 projects which all use the same global AnalyzerConfig file like this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <GlobalAnalyzerConfigFiles Include="$([MSBuild]::NormalizePath('$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)', '.analyzerconfig'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The `.analyzerconfig` file specifies a bunch of rules and severity levels for analyzers:

```
is_global = true

dotnet_sort_system_directives_first = true
csharp_style_var_for_built_in_types = false : warning

dotnet_diagnostic.CA2254.severity   = warning
dotnet_diagnostic.CS4014.severity   = error

# ...other rules omitted for clarity
```

We currently have the `.analyzerconfig` file copied across all of our Git repositories which is becoming increasingly painful to maintain as we configure more rules. I'm looking for a way to serve this file from a NuGet package to all of our projects.

When we configure more rules, we'd like to be able to change *only* the AnalyzerConfig file in the NuGet project, push a new version of the package, and wait for our bot to process the dependency updates overnight, so we can delete all the duplicated AnalyzerConfig files from the projects and not worry about them becoming outdated.

So ideally, I'd want to:

1. Include the global AnalyzerConfig file in the NuGet package.
2. Install the NuGet package in every project, and point to the file (located in the installed package) via the `GlobalAnalyzerConfigFiles` property in all of our projects.

I prefer not to have the global AnalyzerConfig file present in all of our Git repositories; a custom build task that copies the file to somewhere in the project directory is not really what I'd like to have. It should come from the NuGet package only, however I'm not entirely sure if this is possible. If it's not possible, I guess the best way would be to just gitignore the copied files in every repository.

**Is it possible to configure the `GlobalAnalyzerConfigFiles` property to point to a file inside a NuGet package? And if so, how would I achieve this?**

I've searched the docs and various articles but couldn't find any information on how to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As documented [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/msbuild-props-and-targets), you can put a `<PackageId>.props` file inside one of the `build`, `buildMultiTargeting` or `buildTransitive` folders in your nuget package.

If your package is named "MyPackage", and you decide to use the `build` folder, the contents of your nuget package can be:

```
build/MyPackage.analyzerconfig
build/MyPackage.props
```

The `MyPackage.props` file in the `build` folder will be referenced automatically by any project directly referencing it via `<PackageReference>`. It's content can be:

```
<Project>
  <ItemGroup>
    <GlobalAnalyzerConfigFiles
      Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)MyPackage.analyzerconfig" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```